# Python / Airflow - how to transmit information between past/prior task executions

Tags: python, task, airflow

I'm setting up a new Airflow instance. I am looking to access data/information from the prior task execution, and don't see a clear way to do it.

I have used xcoms to transfer data between tasks within a DAG, and know variables can be used globally. I figure there is or should be an easy way to transmit this information, but can't find it. Along the lines of xcoms, I'm only looking to transfer small amounts of data.

A simplification of what I'm looking to do:

I have a `resource_monitor` DAG that checks various resources on the server. There are a couple tasks that look at disk usage:

`record_disk_usage` logs the current usage and decides whether to trigger or skip `alert_disk_usage`, which sends email alerts when a threshold has been reached.

I want to transmit the timestamp and threshold for the last email that was sent to avoid spammy results. Let's say we hit 90% disk usage and sent a warning email. `alert_disk_usage` should retrieve the threshold and timestamp and be skipped for 24 hours from the first email if we stay at ~90% usage. However, the DAG should still run every 20 minutes because, should we hit 95% usage, a new alert should go out in (nearly) real time.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in mechanism in airflow foreseen for that. Airflow traditionally is used to run on "data intervals" (like an hour, or day) and each run is supposed to be fully idempotent, and fully rerunnable from the scratch, without relying on "state" of other intervals. This is a very basic premise of most of the Airflow usages - and it allows things like "backfill" of the data - so rerunning any tasks from any number of past runs to re-process the data for that particular interval.

There are however usages like yours, that are a bit different, and Airflow is good (And will be better in upcoming versions - especially after implementing
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/AIRFLOW/AIP-39+Richer+scheduler_interval ). There are couple of things you can use to get what you want:

1. Store the state of your runs in a GCS/S3 and pull it in your custom operator - this gives you full control of storing and retrieving richer/bigger amounts of data, versioning and the like.
2. Store the state of your run (maybe latest run only) in an Airflow Variable. That has the advantage, that you do not have to have an external storage, and also that you can retrieve the Variable via JINJA macros in your operator, so you just have to have a custom operator to store the variable, the "retrieval" part might be achieved by embedding the right JINJA macron in a templated field of your operator https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/macros-ref.html (but probably anyway you will have to write a custom operator and use Python API to access the variable). The limitation of that is that Variables are stored in metadata-db and have limited capacity, but I think for your case it should  be enough. You can keep even somewhat structured data (json string for one) and save/retrieve that as string in variable. The Python API for Variables has even support for direct reading/writing json dicts (it will serialize/deserialize it automatically).

Comment: Hi Jarek - I think you're also the person who responded to my github comments.  Just to follow up on this (for future readers).   

We did following your 2nd suggestion and used variables. Because the data was a bit more specific, we stored a multi-level json object and used [de]serialize_json for storage and retrieval. It has been running well for over a month now.

Initially I was concerned that there was no option to scope a variable to a specific dag, and so with multiple Airflow managers they could end up writing conflicting variable names, but that's unlikely in this case.